# Require Company Email to see website

Tags: email, login

I was wondering if there is a way to require a customer to have a company email address in order to view our website. I found a solution that requires a visitor to sign in/sign up in order to view the store but nothing for specific email address. I want something to require our company's email address in order to see anything. Free and simple is the best.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tutorial here: http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/

But short and simple, you just need to add a .js file (call it whatever you want) in your js/ directory.

Example: inchoo.js
Contents (from the tutorial, only accepting gmail addresses):

```
Validation.add('validate-email', 'Please enter a valid Gmail address. For example johndoe@gmail.com.', function(v) {
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]*@gmail\.com)$/i.test(v)
})
```

In the code above, just change the message 'Please enter a valid.....' to whatever you like, and change @gmail\.com to @yourcompanydomain\.com.

Then include it the website's head.
Again, from the tutorial:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>inchoo.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

I already have a custom module, so I dropped it into one of my existing layout files, but this should also work if you add it in to a local.xml file.

If you don't *have* a local.xml file, you can add one to your theme at `app/design/frontend/default/<your_theme>/layout/local.xml` or `app/design/frontend/<your_theme>/default/layout/local.xml` (however your theme is structured).

The contents should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
<default>
    <reference name="head">
<action method="addJs"><script>inchoo.js</script></action>
</reference>
</default>
</layout>
```